# is there a level of battery decline that would cause Apple to replace the battery under warranty?

Tags: ipad, battery

I have an iPad 9 that is about 10 months old and IDK if I should bring it in before the 1 year is up.

The battery is much weaker than I expected.  Some 6 % in just 10 min without actually running anything.

It won't go into sleep mode automatically and gets warm just sitting there without any app actually being fully running (just 2 in the background).

Overall, I'm not happy with these things and IDK if Apple would do anything about it.

I don't have any extended Apple Care other than what comes with it, and IIRC, it's only the first year.

Answer (score 1):

> I have an iPad 9 that is about 10 months old and IDK if I should bring it in before the 1 year is up.

Yes.  If you have a problem, take it in.  Once the warranty is up, Apple has no obligation to repair/replace your device. They have been known to do things outside the warranty period, but there are no guarantees.

> The battery is much weaker than I expected. Some 6% in just 10 min without actually running anything.

That doesn’t sound too bad, but it may be indicative of a growing issue. It also deprnds on the App.  If it requires lots of CPU and or generates lots of network traffic, it will drain the battery faster than an app that doesn’t require as many resources.

> Overall, I'm not happy with these things and IDK if Apple would do anything about it.

Well, it’s guaranteed that Apple won’t do anything if you don’t take it in.  But, you shouldn’t go in blindly.  There are several battery health apps like [Battery Testing](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/battery-testing/id887730232) or [Battery Life](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/battery-life-check-runtimes/id1080930585) that can supply you with diagnostic info.

There is also the built-in battery status in *Settings -> Battery* that will tell you what’s consuming your battery.